# SearchQuery in a saved search given multiple conditions

Tags: content-search

I am trying to figure out how to give multiple 'AND' conditions in a Saved Search which is under an item bucket.  Currently I have the following

```
location:{0a6536b7-afe8-4121-ae74-ef7501e36491};template:{d9577b16-776f-48c3-b2f8-e31514acd492};custom:IsActive|true
```

However this seems to run OR conditions instead of AND.  How do I change this to an AND?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to check out the Sitecore documentation site on how to properly format the queries. The best article I found is [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/content_authoring/searching/build_a_search_query).

If I understand correctly, you'll want the `+` to appear in the query. When using the query builder, click the icon until it changes to the green plus.